# Bulk log download from GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, bulkloader

I'd like to download all my logs to a file with "appcfg.py".

I don't use app.yaml, but I wrote a very simple one:

```
"application: myAppId 
version: 1 
runtime: java"
```

I use this command:

```
python appcfg.py --append request_logs "app.yaml's path"  logs.txt
```

And I always get:

```
Value 'java' for key runtime does not match expression '^python$' in 
"app.yaml's path", line 3, column 10
```

What should I do to download all my logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the Java runtime, so take a look at:

> http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs

And the arguments can be found here:

> http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Command_Line_Arguments

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about this. I only knew about the python stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity, if you are using Eclipse, the Java `appcfg.sh` script can be found inside of the Eclipse plugins directory where the GAE SDK gets installed.  On my Mac this is in:

```
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4/bin/appcfg.sh
```

I chdir'd inside my GAE project folder that is running in Eclipse and then ran it like:

```
sh /Applications/Eclipse/.../bin/appcfg.sh request_logs war log_output.txt
```

The `war` is the directory of your war files inside your project.  You should see:

```
> ls war/WEB-INF/lib 
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.6.jar
appengine-jsr107cache-1.6.6.jar
...
```

The script runs the jar file which should prompt you for your email and password (I don't know how/if they are protecting it).  If you are using the [two-factor auth configured](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth) then you'll need to utilize the `--oauth2` parameter.  This requires (I guess) a 1.7.X version of the SDK because it wasn't available in 1.6.6.  Of course their docs don't talk about versions.